# Coldfusion Application.cfc

Tags: coldfusion, application.cfc

This may be a stupid question, but when my datasource is in a cfm page it will work just fine, but when I put the datasource in my application.cfc it errors out.

Code from CFM file

```
<cfquery name = "getlist" datasource="jeb48_shoppingcart">
 SELECT ProductID, ProductName, ProductQty, ProductPrice, ProductDescription
 FROM Products;
</cfquery>
```

Code from CFC

```
<cfcomponent> 
   <cfset This.name = "TestApplication"> 
   <cfset This.clientStorage = "jeb48_northwind"> 
   <cfset This.clientmanagement="True"> 
   <cfset This.loginstorage="Session"> 
   <cfset This.sessionmanagement="True"> 
   <cfset This.sessiontimeout="#createtimespan(0,0,10,0)#"> 
   <cfset This.applicationtimeout="#createtimespan(5,0,0,0)#"> 
</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: For next time, "errors out" is very vague. If you are getting an error, please include the *actual* error message.

Comment: Did you try changing the order and setting clientmanagement before setting clientStorage? Also make sure your database is configured for client variables, see: http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=sharedVars_08.html

Make sure you setup the CDATA and CGLOBAL tables as outlined in the link above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your Application.cfc is not setting the datasource correctly.

`clientstorage` is used by `client` variables - [read more about that here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0c35c-7fd5.html)

`datasource` is used for cfquery datasources:

`<cfset this.datasource="cfartgallery">`

You can read more about the `datasource` property [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSd160b5fdf5100e8f790124b112a3b8b2adb-8000.html)

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to define your datasource as an application variable witin your onapplication start. If you have multiple datasources you could use an application variable containing a structure of datasources. Antony is correct, you are only creating a reference to the datasource for client storage. This does not mean it works.

```
<cfset APPLICATION.dsn = {}>
<cfset APPLICATION.dsn.main = "jeb48_northwind">
<cfset APPLICATION.dsn.logging = "loggingDataSource">

<cfquery name = "getlist" datasource="#APPLICATION.dsn.main#">
SELECT ProductID, ProductName, ProductQty, ProductPrice, ProductDescription
FROM Products;
</cfquery>
```

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question. :)

Comment: This is what i understood as the solution from the question as well. The "this" scope in Application.cfc does not get copied to the "application" scope.

Comment: the `datasource` does not need to go in the `application` scope. Defining a datasource means you can entirely omit the datasource property in a `cfquery` eg `<cfquery name="getlist">`. more details available http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1642-learning-coldfusion-9-application-specific-data-sources.htm

Comment: No need to use the Application scope for handling this problem, using `this.datasource` works just fine.